# Deserialize JSON string in c#

Tags: c#, json

I didn't find any solution to deseralize following JSON String

How to deserialize following JSON string in c#

```js
{
"1":[
        {"cityId":93,"cityName":"Tapah","cityCode":"TAP"},
        {"cityId":3,"cityName":"Melaka","cityCode":"MLK"},
        {"cityId":6,"cityName":"Kota Bharu","cityCode":"KB"},
        {"cityId":7,"cityName":"Dungun","cityCode":"DG"}
    ],
"2":[
        {"cityId":77,"cityName":"Grik","cityCode":"GRIK"},
        {"cityId":6,"cityName":"Kota Bharu","cityCode":"KB"},
        {"cityId":7,"cityName":"Dungun","cityCode":"DG"},
        {"cityId":98,"cityName":"Bangan Serai","cityCode":"BS"}
    ],
"6":[
        {"cityId":3,"cityName":"Melaka","cityCode":"MLK"},
        {"cityId":82,"cityName":"Teluk Intan","cityCode":"TI"},
        {"cityId":7,"cityName":"Dungun","cityCode":"DG"}
    ]
}
```

I am getting  integer, set of city details object

Please kindly advise me to deserialize

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSON.Net to do this very easily:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JSONObject);
```

http://james.newtonking.com/json

**Example from web site**

```
string json = @"{
  'Name': 'Bad Boys',
  'ReleaseDate': '1995-4-7T00:00:00',
  'Genres': [
    'Action',
    'Comedy'
  ]
}";

Movie m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(json);

string name = m.Name;
// Bad Boys
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the best solutions Newtonsoft.Json library, that included in every .NET 4.5 solution as I know. You can do this way:

```
public class Movie
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}

// read file into a string and deserialize JSON to a type
Movie movie1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(File.ReadAllText(@"c:\movie.json"));

// deserialize JSON directly from a file
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"c:\movie.json"))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    Movie movie2 = (Movie)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(Movie));
}
```

Or if you want deserialize Object:

```
public class Account
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Roles { get; set; }
}

string json = @"{
  'Email': 'james@example.com',
  'Active': true,
  'CreatedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00Z',
  'Roles': [
    'User',
    'Admin'
  ]
}";

Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);
Console.WriteLine(account.Email);
```