# How can I deserialize JSON string in C#?

Tags: c#, json, public

I have the following string:

```
{
  "time": 20200526, 
  "data1m": "[[1590451620,204.73,204.81,204.73,204.81,1.00720100],[1590451680,204.66,204.66,204.58,204.58,1.00000000],[1590452280,204.65,204.83,204.65,204.83,13.74186800],[1590452820,203.75,203.75,203.75,203.75,0.50000000],[1590452880,203.47,203.47,203,203,1.60000000],[1590453000,203.06,203.06,203.06,203.06,4.00000000]]"
}
```

How can I de-serialize it in C#?

I use this code:

```
result = reader.ReadToEnd();
var desc = Utilities.Jsprocessor.Deserialize<fooString>(result);

Internal class fooString
{
     public string time { get; set; }
     public string data1m { get; set; }
}
```

However, I would still need to process the string.
Is there a way to de-serialize it so that it will be saved in an array?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26922223/deserialize-json-string-in-c-sharp

Comment: please take note that there's an " before and after the [] 
I am using the JSON file sent from https://cex.io/api/ohlcv/hd/20200526/ETH/USD

Comment: After deserializing the JSON to `fooString`, then deserialize `fooString.data1m` to a `double[][]`.

Comment: From what library is the method `Utilities.Jsprocessor.Deserialize`?  I can't find anything via google.

Answer (score 2):

This will be a data aware way of doing it. ***I read the json from a file called json1.json***

**Custom Converter**

```
public class StringToListConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.Value is null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        List<double[]> retVal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<double[]>>(reader.Value.ToString());
        return retVal;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public class model
{
    public int time { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringToListConverter<List<int>>))]
    public List<double[]> data1m { get; set; }
}
```

**Sample execution**

```
public string jsonData = "";
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("json1.json"))
    {
        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
        Console.Write(json);
        var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<model>(json);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string text = {
  "time": 20200526, 
  "data1m": "[[1590451620,204.73,204.81,204.73,204.81,1.00720100],[1590451680,204.66,204.66,204.58,204.58,1.00000000],[1590452280,204.65,204.83,204.65,204.83,13.74186800],[1590452820,203.75,203.75,203.75,203.75,0.50000000],[1590452880,203.47,203.47,203,203,1.60000000],[1590453000,203.06,203.06,203.06,203.06,4.00000000]]"
}

string deserializedText = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(text);
```

Note: For JsonConvert, use NuGet Package :- "Newtonsoft.Json"